# Testing the MariaDB shared library using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, mariadb

I have built MariaDB 10.0.15 from source (with the WITH_EMBEDDED_SERVER flag) and would like to test its shared library using a simple program. I'm a total beginner with CMake.

My program is the following one :

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);

    if (con == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        exit(1);
    }

    if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "root", "root_pswd",
            NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (mysql_query(con, "CREATE DATABASE testdb"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(1);
    }

    mysql_close(con);
    exit(0);
}
```

I created the following CMakeLists.txt file :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(mariadb_simple_test)

add_subdirectory(/usr/src/mariadb-10.0.15/libmysqld mariadb)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(mariadb_simple_test ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Is this the good way of doing it ? When trying to build it, CMake complains with the following error : *Unknown CMake command "ADD_CONVENIENCE_LIBRARY"*, which makes me think that some CMake module is probably missing, but why ?

Answer (score 1):

The add_subdirectory is invalid, because add_subdirectory is used to fetch other CMakeLists.txt files

You should set the compiler include folders with, this should be the install folder of your compiled mariadb:

```
include_directories("<your folder with headers>")
```

Then you should link against libmysqlclient.so with:

```
target_link_libraries(mariadb_simple_test "mysqlclient")
```

Have a look at beyond linux from scratch to build MariaDB from source:
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/server/mariadb.html

You should probably edit the CMakeCache.txt file after your did run cmake command to point the installation folder to e.g /opt/mariadb/

I leave setting the library search path from CMake as extra homework :-)